# Which google cloud storage will be most appropriate for my data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am planning to migrate my complete system to google cloud platform. Currently it i am running combination of mysql, apache, nodejs and angular js. Mysql is getting slower day by day as data is increasing exponentially. System deals with big data analytics. I need IO intensive db with shortest query timings. Currently i have structured mysql database and as per requirements of the application i need to query data very frequently  for analytics as well as raw data. Google is suggesting me to use Cloud Bigtable but having no experience with any of the services i am not sure about it.

Kindly suggest me most appropriate google cloud db for my application out of cloud spanner, cloud sql, cloud datastore, big query and cloud big table.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

PS: I am thinking of using google compute engine with it.

Comment: I am not an expert on Bigtable, however I want to tell you to think carefully before using the Cloud Datastore. While easy to use and performs well, it only allows you 200 composite indexes. If you have a lot of analytics, I doubt it would be useful for you. If you are already using MySQL you can always just use Cloud SQL and set up a MySQL DB.

Cloud Spanner is a NewSQL DB and I would not make such jump to a totally new DB system without reading carefully about its advantages and disadvantages first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of videos from Google's Cloud Next conference (2017) that covers your questions. The following video focuses primarily on Cloud Datastore but I strongly recommend you watch the first 15-20 minutes. It does a good job of covering the other database options Google provides and which contexts they are best suited for.

[Cloud Datastore 101: Overview of Google's scalable NoSQL document database (Google Cloud Next '17)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZDk0NZGqHs)

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud BigTable looks like the best candidate for your requirement.

Checkout this storage options comparison page from Google Cloud - https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/ . It has a decision tree/flow chart to help shortlist a storage option as per project requirement.